# Abelian Lie group implies abelian Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Here is the exercise from Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold 8-25

> Prove that if $G$ is an abelian Lie group, then $Lie(G)$ is abelian. [Hint: show that the inversion map $i:G\rightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism, and use $di_e: T_eG\rightarrow T_eG$ is given by $di_e(X)=-X$.]

where $Lie(G)$ is defined as all left-invariant vector fields. I don't know how to get started on this. Does anyone know why the hint helps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already know how to start based on the hints. What  is your work so far?

Comment: @SiKucing  I try to use coordinate formula for Lie bracket to compute directly. But the computation is a bit lengthy and seems does not work... (Basically I just don't know how to use this hint...)

Comment: Do not use coordinates for this one. I leave some sketch in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ abelian, then $i$ is a Lie group homomorphism and hence $i_* : \text{Lie}(G) \to \text{Lie}(G)$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, where for each $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$, $i_*X \in \text{Lie}(G)$ is a $i$-related vector field to $X$. By the second hint, we can show that for any $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$,
$$
i_*X = -X. 
$$
Hence for any $X,Y \in \text{Lie}(G)$,
$$
-[X,Y] = i_*[X,Y] =\cdots= [X,Y] \implies [X,Y] = 0.
$$

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!

Comment: Why is $i_*X = -X$? I can't figure out how to show this from $(i_*X)_e = -X_e$ which is what we get from using the hint. Is $i_*X$ left invariant as well? 8-24(b) shows that it is right invariant, so I'm not sure if it is left invariant as well.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I haven't touch math for loong time. But fortunately I've still have my notes with me. Seems like I used Theorem 8.44, that is use the fact that $i_*X$ is $i-$related to X. So you can start with this $i_*X|_g = (di_e(X_e))^{\text{L}}|_g$. Cheers!